# How to get ID from a input field and DELETE by that ID in ReactJS and Axios

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, http

I want to delete a specific object with a DELETE request from **Axios**:

This is my code to fill and get the object information:

```
const rowEvents = {
  onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
    this.setState({
      carId: this.state.cars[rowIndex].carId,
      brand: this.state.cars[rowIndex].brand,
      model: this.state.cars[rowIndex].model,
      color: this.state.cars[rowIndex].color,
      topSpeed: this.state.cars[rowIndex].topSpeed
    });
  }
};
```

When I click on the row I get the data in my input fields:

This is my **delete function**

```
handleDelete = carId => {
  axios
    .delete("https://localhost:44369/api/car/DeleteCar/", {
      params: { id: carId }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

To get the Id from the field I have a input hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="carId" value={this.state.carId} />;
```

After the fields are filled I want to delete this object based on the ID I click on the row:

```
 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger mr-1" onClick={this.handleDelete(document.getElementById("carId"))}> Delete record</button>
```

I get the following error in my console:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I have tried to pass the parameter like this `{this.state.carId}`

Still no succes

Solutions I have tried:

[how to delete a single item using axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694011/how-to-delete-a-single-item-using-axios-in-react)

[How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele)

[How to get the value of an input field using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683770/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-field-using-reactjs)

How can I delete the object based on the ID in the input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to pass `carId` as a parameter because you are saving it to the state.

you can access the `carId` by calling `this.state.carId`

```
handleDelete = () => {
  axios
    .delete("https://localhost:44369/api/car/DeleteCar/", {
      params: { id: this.state.carId }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: What if the OP has number of rows, and each row has delete button?

Comment: if it is inside a map you can do it like data.map(item => { <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger mr-1" onClick={this.handleDelete(item.carId)}> Delete record</button>
})

Comment: Nice this is working! Thank you so much for your time

Comment: from the question it is clear that the carId is stored in a state variable

Comment: In this case your code fails, better you edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing a `console.log(document.getElementById("carId"))`? I suspect you are getting the whole element, not just the value that you assigned it. I think that changing it to `onClick={this.handleDelete(document.getElementById("carId").value)}` will fix your problem.